# How to create collections that are edited in admin?

Tags: plugin-development, events

I'm not sure what this feature is called, but I've seen examples of this before. Lets say, on my site I want additional collections of things (besides blog posts) that have their own sections in the admin area.

For example, I have:

- a list of events
- a list of products
- a list of testimonials

...and they each need their own page to list them.

How does this work in WordPress and how can I create my own?

Comment: You mean custom taxonomy terms and their archive pages for listing and categorising, and custom post types?

Comment: Your requirement can be fulfilled with Custom Post Type UI  and Custom Post Type List Shortcode plugins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe what you're referring to is called **"Post Types"**. By default, WordPress has a complete post types you're already familiar with - `post` ( news / blog ), `page` ( Pages ), `attachment` ( Media ), `revision` ( Page / Post Revisions ). You can read up on the full list of built in post types on [The Codex - Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

If you want to register a *new* Custom Post Type ( CPT ) you can do pretty easily with some PHP knowledge. Let's go through and create our own post type called "Products".

**Step One** - Connect to FTP - you **do not** want to do this using `Appearance -> Editor`.

**Step Two** - Locate your theme, if you're using a child theme open that up and locate the `functions.php` file. Open the file in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or your editor of choice.

**Step Three** - Register Your Post Type

Toward the top of your `functions.php` file we're going to *hook* into WordPress [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) and use a built-in WordPress function cleverly called: [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). I *highly* suggest you read these codex links as I will not explain each point but instead give a brief description.

```
/** Create Post Type **/
function cpt_init() {

    // Products Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'cpt_products', array(                  // Internal name `cpt_products` - this is what we test against in queries
        'labels'            =>  array(                          // An array of Administrative labels
            'name'          =>      __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' =>      __( 'Product' ),
            'all_items'     =>      __( 'View Products' ),
            'add_new'       =>      __( 'New Product' ),
            'add_new_item'  =>      __( 'New Product' ),
            'edit_item'     =>      __( 'Edit Product' ),
            'view_item'     =>      __( 'View Product' ),
            'search_items'  =>      __( 'Search Products' ),
            'no_found'      =>      __( 'No Products Found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Products in Trash' )
        ),
        'public'            =>  true,                           // Whether it will be publically available or only in the admin panel
        'publicly_queryable'=>  true,                           // "                                                                "
        'show_ui'           =>  true,                           // Whether we want this post type to show up in the admin panel
        'show_in_nav_menus' =>  false,                          // If we want Products to show up in the `Appearance -> Menu`
        'capability_type'   =>  'page',                         // Mostly used for user capability
        'hierarchical'      =>  false,                          // If you will allow products to have child products / assigned a parent
        'rewrite'           =>  array( 'slug' => 'product', 'with_front' => false ),        // This is going to be what the single post will be located at `/product/product-name/`
        'menu_icon'         =>  'dashicons-cart',               // https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#welcome-widgets-menus
        'menu_position'     =>  5,                              // Where you want it to show up in the admin panel
        'supports'          =>  array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'revisions' )  // What is actually shown when a new product is added - admin panel
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_init' );
```

**Step Four** - Upload `functions.php` - an important note here is to also **flush permalinks** which is as easy as going to `Settings -> Permalinks` and click "Save" button at the bottom of the page.

---

Similar to creating a post type, if you want to create *Categories* ( similar to Post Categories ) you can do so using the [`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function. Follow the steps as above until Step 3.

**Step 3** - Register Taxonomy

The first two parameters are important to link the taxonomy to the post type. The next important part is the `hierarchical` parameter - this will be the difference between [`post_tags`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Tags_Screen) ( false ) and [`categories`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Categories_Screen) ( true ). We will make this taxonomy hierarchical which is similar to post categories.

```
/** Add Custom Taxonomy **/
function tax_init() {
    // Product Categories
    register_taxonomy( 
        'tax_products',         // Taxonomy slug
        'cpt_products',         // What post type we're assigning the taxonomy to.
        array(                  // Array of Arguments
            'labels'            =>  array(                                  // User Friendly Labels
                'name'              => __( 'Product Categories' ),
                'singular_name'     => __( 'Product Category' ),
                'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
                'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
                'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
                'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
                'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
                'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' )
            ),
            'public'            =>  true,               // Whether it will be public or only used in the admin panel
            'hierarchical'      =>  true,               // The differnce between *Tags* and *Categories*
            'show_in_nav_menus' =>  true,               // To show up in `Appearance -> Menus` or not.
            'show_admin_column' =>  true,               // If we want an column next to the title when listing our products
            'rewrite'           =>  array( 'slug' => 'products/category', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true )       // Similar to post type, where to find the categories `products/category/category-1/`
        ) 
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tax_init');
```

Comment: [This site](http://generatewp.com/post-type/) automatically generates the CPT code for you. Very handy :)

Comment: @BenFreke that whole website looks pretty nifty, good find!

Answer (score 0):

These are called **custom post types**. There are several ways to create new post type, using a plugin or creating yourself.

- If you prefer using a plugin, try this- https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
- If you want to create them yourself without any plugins, you need to add some codes to `functions.php` file in your theme. This is a simple example:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Books'
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

This will add a new type of content(post) called Book.

See codex page for details -https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type