# Duplicate "Pages" Item in Admin Menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I'm registering the following post type:

```
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public'       => true
) );
```

Now I have duplicate "Pages" menu items in WordPress Admin Menu. It should be not "Pages" but rather "Posts".

In older versions of WordPress ( < 4.4 ) everything was alright. Any suggestions to do the same? Most important is to make my posts hierarchical.

[image: Duplicate "Pages" Image]

Comment: Well posts aren't hierarchical - pages are. Trying to change that potentially opens a can of worms. Why don't you just use pages? Or a custom post type? Any reasons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post type register stoped working after update 4.4](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211357/post-type-register-stoped-working-after-update-4-4)

Comment: @kraftner is correct. Trying to clobber a Core Post type is a bad, bad idea. Why are you (and why do you need to) convert the "Post" type into, essentially, the "Page" type? You already have pages.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate onto why the labels are "Pages" and not "Posts" but I do know that `post` is on the list of reserved post types. The fact is that `post` is *already registered* by default as your normals Posts so you cannot re-register it. Here's a list of [Default Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) with their respective post type slugs.

What you want to do is actually create your own [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types). [Steps to register Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185591/7355).